# SQL Partition By Function without aggregation

Tags: sql

I have a table with data like the following:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Value
SQ03    | D       | 1000040 | 1000
SQ03    |         | 1000040 | 1000
SQ03    |         | 1000050 | 2000
SQ03    |         | 1000060 | 3000
SQ03    | L       | 1000060 | 3000
SQ03    | D       | 1000060 | 3000
```

What I need to do is to get a single value based on column3. Is a value in column3 is unique, I need to get that value. But if there are duplicates in Column3, I need to get the value where Column2 is not null. But like in the example that I showed in above, there are values for Column3 where Column2 is marked more than once, in these cases I need to get only one of these values, doesn't matter what.

So I thought on flagging which line I would need with the following solution:

```
select *, CASE
WHEN "Column2" != ' '  
THEN 'X'
WHEN "Column2" = ' ' AND row_number() over(PARTITION BY "Column3" ORDER BY "Column2" DESC, "Column3") = 1
THEN 'X'  
ELSE 'O'
END AS "FLAG" from DUMMY
WHERE "Column1" = 'SQ03'
```

But the problem with this solution is that it's aggregating the value from Column3. Like, it sums the values where Column3 has duplicates.

Can anyone help me with a solution where I don't get the values aggregated?

EDIT:
My expected output would be this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Value
SQ03    | D       | 1000040 | 1000
SQ03    |         | 1000050 | 2000
SQ03    | L       | 1000060 | 3000
```

Comment: may be you can test with : Select Top 1 * where "Column1" = 'SQ03' order by Column2

Comment: What is your expected output for the sample data you have shown?

Comment: I'm baffled by what your code has to do with your question.  One is about getting a value.  The other sets a flag.

Comment: @Nick I've updated the thread with my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to generate row numbers for each `Column3` value (ordered by `Column2 DESC` to make `NULL` values come last), and then select the rows which have `row_number = 1`:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Value
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column3 ORDER BY Column2 DESC) AS rn
  FROM DUMMY
  WHERE Column1 = 'SQ03'
) D
WHERE rn = 1
```

Alternatively you can use a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column3 ORDER BY Column2 DESC) AS rn
  FROM DUMMY
  WHERE Column1 = 'SQ03'
)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Value
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Output for both queries:

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Value
SQ03        D           1000040     1000
SQ03        (null)      1000050     2000
SQ03        L           1000060     3000
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53312/3)

Comment: That did the trick @Nick! I've learned something new today! Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think an aggregation function (as a window function) does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       max(column3) over (partition by column1)
from t;
```